# Highchart Time Data With Irregular Interval and Text

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Im trying to make some modification of Highchart Time data with irregular intervals (spline-irregular-time) like this http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/

So, I want to modify the UTC Array in order to put some aditional text data.

I change the array to an object and put the UTD data for original example into a variable "y" without success.

Thanks in advance.

This is my modified code:

```
$(function() {
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Snow depth at Vikjafjellet, Norway'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Irregular time data in Highcharts JS'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            month: '%e. %b',
            year: '%b'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Snow depth (m)'
        },
        min: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return 'Extra data: <b>' + this.point.myData + '</b>';
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        spline: {
            marker: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },

    series:

        [{
        name: 'Foo',


        data: [{
            y: [Date.UTC(2016, 7, 29), 1.0],
            myData: 'firstPoint'
        }, {
            y: [Date.UTC(2016, 9, 29), 2.0],
            myData: 'secondPoint'
        }, {
            y: [Date.UTC(2016, 9, 29), 3.18],
            myData: 'thirdPoint'
        }],

    }],     
});
});
```

Comment: *"I change the array to an object and put the UTD data for original example into a variable "y" without success."* Of course not, "y" needs to be the `y` data point value. What are you trying to actually do with the `myData` value?

Answer (score 1):

The point object does not have a valid format, y should be a number, not an array.

```
    {
        x: Date.UTC(2016, 7, 29),
        y: 1.0,
        myData: 'firstPoint'
    }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/reutw7gb/

There is also an optional way to configure points as arrays. You can set series `keys` property.

```
  keys: ['x', 'y', 'myData'],
  data: [
    [Date.UTC(2016, 7, 29), 1.0, 'firstPoint'],
    [Date.UTC(2016, 9, 29), 2.0, 'secondPoint'],
    [Date.UTC(2016, 9, 29), 3.18, 'thirdPoint']
  ],
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/reutw7gb/1/